# Create child account that relies on a parent account to maintain its existential deposit to stay alive and to pay all its fees

Tags: assets, nft, sub-account

Is it possible to generate a child account where:

- The child account transaction fees are deducted from a parent account
- The child account is kept alive with its existential deposit (ED) provided in a parent account on behalf of the child account
- The child account remains alive until the parent account dies
- It is not necessary to make any deposit into the child account
- It is not necessary for the child account to make any initial deposit
- The child account can still receive an nft and assets?

Comment: Do you need the private key for the "child account" to sign transactions, or are they supposed to be signed with the parent account's key?

Comment: Any one of them will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If signing transaction with the "parent account" is acceptable, then I can suggest using a **pure proxy** (a.k.a anonymous proxy) for the "child account". Here are some helpful resources explaining how to set it up and use:

- [Anonymous Proxy – Polkadot wiki](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-proxies#anonymous-proxy-pure-proxy)
- [How to Create a Pure Proxy](https://support.polkadot.network/support/solutions/articles/65000182196)
- [When and Why you can use Anonymous (Pure) Proxies on Polkadot [video]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YkYApbhU3i0)
- [Creating and Deleting Anonymous (Pure) Proxies on Polkadot
  [video]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T443RcCYP24)